# I can't use a disposed TextEditingController when pushed to another screen and popped, is my understanding correct?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a screen to create a post. There is a `TextFormField` there and I added `dispose` to its `TextEditingController`. However, I get an error:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
A TextEditingController was used after being disposed.
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

If my understanding is correct, I think it's saying that I can't use the disposed `TextEditingController` when I'm pushed to another screen and popped. Hope you guys can tell me if my understanding is correct.

I referred [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60557145/16124033) but it didn't solve my problem.

My code:

```dart
TextEditingController messageController = TextEditingController();

class CreatePostScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const CreatePostScreen({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<CreatePostScreen> createState() => _CreatePostScreenState();
}

class _CreatePostScreenState extends ConsumerState<CreatePostScreen> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  void dispose() {
    messageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);

    …

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        …
        title: Text("Create post"),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            …
            TextFormField(
              controller: enquiryMessageController,
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none,
                hintText: "What do you wish to enquire?",
                hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              ),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`messageController` is outside `ConsumerStatefulWidget`, because the code is to make the text in `TextFormField` not disappear, please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74906751/16124033).

Feel free to leave a comment if you need more information.

I can't use a disposed `TextEditingController` when pushed to another screen and popped, is my understanding correct? I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try defining the controller this way:

```js
class CreatePostScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const CreatePostScreen({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<CreatePostScreen> createState() => _CreatePostScreenState();
}

class _CreatePostScreenState extends ConsumerState<CreatePostScreen> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
late TextEditingController messageController;


  @override
  void initState() {
    messageController = TextEditingController();
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    messageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);

    …

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        …
        title: Text("Create post"),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            …
            TextFormField(
              controller: enquiryMessageController,
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none,
                hintText: "What do you wish to enquire?",
                hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              ),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I see you are declaring it as a global variable. When the screen is popped (removed from widget tree), `dispose` is executed. So your global `TextEditingController` is disposed. It is a very bad practice. You need to define it inside `_CreatePostScreenState` class. So whenever the screen widget initiated, a new controller widget will also be created. I hope, this solves your problem. If not, then please edit the question, add error messages, and code lines which you find from error log.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! Yes, I should have given more explanation. I edited.

Comment: Sorry I had Sorry, I misunderstood the meaning of your answer. I think an answer would be best to give some code for the asker to understand. I voted for it.